# Queue has more items that I put in it

Tags: java, debugging, queue

In my Java program, I initialized a Queue with all numbers from 0 to 1000.

```
        emptyFrames = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            emptyFrames.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println("Debug");
```

However, when I go in to debug, there are `1155` items in the Queue.

[image: Debug]
Why is this happening?

Comment: There's a lot of information that's not here.  Where else is the queue used?  What happens if instead of printing "debug" you print `emptyFrames.size()`?

Comment: what happens if you create the queue with an initial capacity of 1000? `emptyFrames = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(1000);`

Comment: Show us the entire code please.

Comment: queue has exactly the number of items you put in but its capacity is much greater than the number of elements added

Comment: `emptyFrames.size()` does indeed return 1000. weird

Comment: @Imray: It's really not weird. How the library code implements the `Queue` should have no bearing on how it behaves. What you are seeing in the debugger is an implementation details.

Comment: not weird if you read the explanation by Vulcan

Comment: @Imray just browsing through old posts; I noticed you had yet to accept an answer (perhaps none of them answer your question?) and I was wondering what was left to be desired in the answers or if you simply had neglected to accept one. I mean no offense in the wording here. It is simply an observation and question.

Answer (score 5):

The indices greater than 1000 are related to the queue's capacity, rather than its size.

Internally, `PriorityQueue` is backed by an array of objects. When adding objects to a queue with a full backing array, the queue will expand the array by a moderate amount by calling `grow`, so that it will have internal space (*capacity*) available for future `add` calls. This avoids the queue having to expand its array every time `add` is called, which would be horribly inefficient.

```
private void grow(int minCapacity) {
    int oldCapacity = queue.length;
    // Double size if small; else grow by 50%
    int newCapacity = oldCapacity + ((oldCapacity < 64) ?
                                     (oldCapacity + 2) :
                                     (oldCapacity >> 1));
    // overflow-conscious code
    if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
        newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
    queue = Arrays.copyOf(queue, newCapacity);
}
```

<sub>Code retrieved from [Docjar](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.java.html).</sub>

Comment: Are you implying that this is a bug with Eclipse as opposed to a bug in the code?

Comment: @Makoto I'm implying neither; this is expected behavior.

Comment: I disagree.  I would not expect the formal size of the queue to be larger than what I had inserted into it.  I don't disagree that the resizing may cause whatever its backing store may be to be a bit *larger* than what I insert into it, but I wouldn't expect that to be reported as part of its size.

Comment: for me this makes perfect sense, can the downvoter explain whats wrong with this answer?

Comment: There's a difference between size and length.

Comment: @Makoto The formal size of the queue is still `1000`; nothing in the question indicates otherwise.  The pictured debug in the question is looking at the queue's backing array.

Comment: This answer is correct. There is a difference between the size of the priority queue and the size of the array backing it. What the OP is seeing is the contents of the backing-array which can be implementation dependent. It's the size of the queue which matters...The downvote should be reversed.

Answer (score 1):

The PriorityQueue internally resizes itself according to its capacity to hold more elements. This is a common feature of collections.

From [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> A priority queue is unbounded, but has an internal capacity governing the size of an array used to store the elements on the queue. It is always at least as large as the queue size. As elements are added to a priority queue, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth policy are not specified.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking at two different pieces of information.

First, the *formal* size of your queue is 1,000 - there are only 1,000 elements in it.  You can verify this with `emptyFrames.size()`.

Second, it appears that Eclipse is showing you the backing array, which is not a good reflection of the total number of elements currently present in the queue.  That array's size will fluctuate [based on its internal resizing rules](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/PriorityQueue.java#PriorityQueue.grow%28int%29).

In this scenario, the backing array isn't something you should trust; only inspect the `size()` of the collection instead.